# How can I get a solution from this Java Program to solve algorithm?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

```
for(int=0; i<1,000,000; i++)
{
     if(data[i]< 0)
        data[i]= data[i] * 2; 
}
```

Hello Everyone,

I would like to know is it possible to calculate the absolute speed of this algorithm below if the time it takes to execute a memory access is 100 nanoseconds and that all other operations (arithmetic, register accesses, etc.) take 10 nanoseconds? I am pretty sure this problem can be used to calculate the absolute speed. I know that we do have one of variables already which is Ta= 100 nanoseconds, right? The rest of the missing variables could be found through the lines of code I have provided after I compile this in Java program? I compiled and ran it, but it doesn't tell what I need to solve this problem. Any suggestions?

Here is the formula that I am using to calculate the absolute speed of this algorithm:

```
T=Tna X Nna + Ta X Na; 

Tna= the time to execute a memory nonaccess instruction; 
Nna= the number of memory nonaccess machine language instructions executed; 
Ta= the time to execute a memory access instruction;
Na= the number of memory access machine language instructions executed;
```

Here is the code that I will compile and run to see if it will give some of the missing variables I need to solve this problem.

Comment: To me, finding the "absolute speed" means you run it and see how long it took.  What did you have in mind?

Comment: @KevinAnderson These are the steps Determine the type of instruction each line of code is, either memory access or non-memory access 
Then you need to determine how many times each will execute. 
Then you add up the number of accesses for each 
You are given the two times: 100 nanoseconds for each memory access instruction and 10 nanoseconds for each non-memory access.

Comment: So by "line of code" did you mean Java code or compiled bytecodes?

Comment: @Kevin Anderson I mean Java code

Comment: @Kevin Anderson Line 1 will execute 1,000,000 million times and is memory access and line 2 will never execute and therefore is nonmemory access, and line 3 will not execute because of the if statement in the second line.

Comment: There are other factors influencing the runtime like cache and page faults. Theoretically one can calculate the max runtime. Still there is no guarantee in a multi process OS.

Comment: @Arun Kumar I going by what I read in my textbook!

Comment: @Arun Kumar I don't have to convert the code into machine language. I only focusing on the steps I have described.

Comment: @Kevin Anderson I am right?

Comment: When you say "line 2 will never execute", do you mean the line that's just `{` or the one that starts `if (...`? Yes, `{` does nothing and takes no time, but the `if` executes a million times and accesses memory while doing so.  The line `data[i[ = data[i] * 2;`, on the "then" branch of the `if`,  will execute anywhere between zero and a million times depending on what values are stored in the `data` array; it's going to do two or three memory accesses each time it does execute.

Comment: @Kevin Anderson I mean the if statement, but I am wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dorakta if your concern on classification of operations in the the code block. Following might be a starting point.

**Line 1:** for(int=0; i<1,000,000; i++)

i variable in for loop, needs memory access and rest operations.
This executs 1,000,000 times

You have:

```
1000000 times of 
2 - memory access (1 read and 1 assign)
1 - compare
1 - incr (depends. It could be -> 1 read and 1 add)
```

**Line 3:** if(data[i]< 0)

data[i] in if statement is a memory reference and a compare operation.
This executs 1,000,000 times

You have:

```
1000000 times of 
2 - memory access
1 - compare
```

**Line 4:** data[i]= data[i] * 2

You have: 0 to 1000000 times depending on value of the data.
You may want to calculate the worst case.

```
Hence, 1000000 times.
2 - memory access (1 read and 1 assign)
1 multiply
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks so much! So the total absolute speed would be 610 seconds because T=Tna X Nna (10 X 1) + Ta X Na (100 x 6);